# Multiple values for one variable?

Tags: php, pdo

I have made a script to add "activities" to a "guide". 
When i have added an activity, the button to add that specific activity must disapear.

Wel, i have made this script:

```
<?php
//userid
$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM user WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."' ";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stm->execute(array());
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$userid = $row['UserID'];
}

//activityid
$sql =  "SELECT activity.*"."FROM user_activity, activity "."WHERE user_activity.ActivityID = activity.ActivityID AND user_activity.UserID = '".$userid."' " ;
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stm->execute(array());
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$activityid = $row['ActivityID'];
}

//Shows activities in database staan.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM activity";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stm->execute(array());   

while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<div id="activity'.$row['ActivityID'].'">';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['ActivityIMG'] ) . '" >', '<br>';
    $instantguide = $row['ActivityID'];
    if($activityid == $instantguide) {
    echo 'this activity is not in your guide.';
    } else {
    echo '<input type="button" class="addActivity" onclick="MakeRequest(' . $instantguide . ')" value="Activiteit toevoegen" data-activity="' . $row['ActivityID'] . '">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Well, there are 2 problems with this script:

1: `$activityid` can only have ONE value, so if i add an activity to my guide, the button of that activity disapears, but when I add another activity to my guide, the button of that activity disapears, but the button of the first activity reapears. That is because the value of `$activityid` changes.

2: i have made an if/else statement to show or not to show the button. In that statement you will finde the `$activityid`. But when there are no activities in the guide, i get the error that `$activityid` does not exists, that is because the variable is made when there is a activity in the guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454781/hide-show-button-also-when-refreshed

Comment: Since there is clearly a one-to-many relationship between guides and activities, you should be focusing on adding more variables/buttons rather than trying to do it with just one.

Answer (score 0):

Make `$activityId` an associative array with one entry per activity id. Then you can use `isset` to determine if the value exists and if it does then set it to 0/1 to decide whether to display that activity button.

More about arrays [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)